# Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery

Below code is throwing error but it was working fine before.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("ul#tab li:first").addClass("aktif");
        $("div.tab_icerik").hide();
        $("div.tab_icerik:first").show();
        $("ul#tab li").click(function (e) {
            var index = $(this).index();
            $("ul#tab li").removeClass("aktif");
            $(this).addClass("aktif");
            $("div.tab_icerik").hide();
            $("div.tab_icerik:eq(" + index + ")").show();
            return false
        });

        $(".tabv2").click(function () {
            var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
            var thatId = $(this).siblings().attr('id')
            $('[class^="tabv2-"]').hide();
            $('.' + thisId).show();
            $('.tabv2').removeClass('tabv2-active');
            $(this).addClass('tabv2-active');
        });

        $(".tabv2plain").click(function () {
            var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
            var thatId = $(this).siblings().attr('id')
            $('[class^="tabv2plain-"]').hide();
            $('.' + thisId).show();
            $('.tabv2plain').removeClass('tabv2plain-active');
            $(this).addClass('tabv2plain-active');
        });

        $(".tabv3plain").click(function () {
            var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
            var thatId = $(this).siblings().attr('id')
            $('[class^="tabv3plain-"]').hide();
            $('.' + thisId).show();
            $('.tabv3plain').removeClass('tabv3plain-active');
            $(this).addClass('tabv3plain-active');
        });
    });
</script>

<div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

            <div class="row" style="padding-top:5px">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul id="tab">
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="#">QESH MANUAL</a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="margin-left:3px;" class="aktif">
                            <a href="#">RELATED SOPs</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="padding-top:5px">
                <div class="tab_icerik" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span style="display:block;">
                            <div id="accordionA1" class="panel-group">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#E51400; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA1" href="#collapseOne">SUNWAY CONSTRUCTION                     </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <!-- SECOND LEVEL ACCORDION START -->
                                            <div id="accordionA2" class="panel-group">
                                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA2" href="#collapseOneOne">QESH MANUAL</a>
                                                        </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="collapseOneOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <div class="group row clear" id="tabsv2plain">
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain tabv2plain-active" id="tabv2plain-1">QESH Manual</div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA2" href="#collapseOneTwo">PROCEDURES MANUALS</a>
                                                        </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="collapseOneTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div1">
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-2">Tender &amp; Contract Procedure Manual</div>
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-3">Procurement Procedure Manual</div>
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-4">Pre-Construction &amp; Planning Procedure Manual</div>
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-5">Project Implementation &amp; Management Procedure Manual</div>
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-6">Post-Construction Procedure Manual</div>
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-7">Management System Administration Procedure Manual</div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA2" href="#collapseOneThree">QESH POLICY</a>
                                                        </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="collapseOneThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div2">
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-8">QESH Policy</div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA2" href="#collapseOneFour">QESH OBJECTIVE</a>
                                                        </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="collapseOneFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div3">
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-9">QESH Objective</div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- SECOND LEVEL ACCORDION END -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#E51400; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA1" href="#collapseTwo">SUNWAY ENGINEERING                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div4">
                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-10">QESH Manual</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#E51400; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA1" href="#collapseThree">SUNWAY GEOTECHNICS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div5">
                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-11">QESH Manual</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#E51400; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA1" href="#collapseFour">SUNWAY CONCRETE PRODUCTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div6">
                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-12">QESH Manual</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <span style="display:block; padding:10px;">
                            <div class="tabplaincontent">
                                <div class="tabv2plain-1" style="display:block;">
                                    One Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-2" style="display:none;">
                                    Two Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-3" style="display:none;">
                                    Three Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-4" style="display:none;">
                                    Four Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-5" style="display:none;">
                                    Five Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-6" style="display:none;">
                                    Six Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-7" style="display:none;">
                                    Seven Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-8" style="display:none;">
                                    Eight Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-9" style="display:none;">
                                    Nine Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-10" style="display:none;">
                                    Ten Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-11" style="display:none;">
                                    Eleven Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-12" style="display:none;">
                                    Twelve Content
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab_icerik" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span style="display:block;">
                            <div id="accordionB1" class="panel-group">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#E51400; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionB1" href="#collapseFive">FINANCE &amp; ADMIN</a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="group row clear" id="tabsv3plain">
                                                <div class="tabv3plain" id="tabv3plain-1">General</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#E51400; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionB1" href="#collapseSix">HUMAN RESOURCES</a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div7">
                                                <div class="tabv3plain" id="tabv3plain-2">General</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#E51400; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionB1" href="#collapseSeven">LEGAL</a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div8">
                                                <div class="tabv3plain" id="tabv3plain-3">General</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#E51400; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionB1" href="#collapseEight">SCCM</a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseEight" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div9">
                                                <div class="tabv3plain" id="tabv3plain-4">General</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <span style="display:block; padding:10px;">
                            <div class="tabplaincontent">
                                <div class="tabv3plain-1" style="display:block;">
                                    Thirteen Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv3plain-2" style="display:none;">
                                    Fourteen Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv3plain-3" style="display:none;">
                                    Fifteen Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv3plain-4" style="display:none;">
                                    Sixteen Content
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

I even tried to change the order of the jQuery reference (by referring the other articles related to the same issue), but still the issue is same.

I don't know what suddenly went wrong in my code.

It is working fine here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYrOQa ,
and when I added this code to Visual Studio (locally), it was working fine there too but suddenly I ended up with below error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: You can't execute jQuery code before you include the jQuery library.

Comment: As stated already, you'll need to include the jQuery library before trying to call it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I wonder how come the same code was working for the first time when I added it to Visual Studio?! But thank you Darren and j08691 , issue resolved now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the jQuery library before using any jQuery functions.

To be safe, you can call the jQuery library from your head section,

```
<head>
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
</head>
```

**HOWEVER**, for a better performance, all the scripts should be written after all the HTML elements are loaded(just before the `</body>` tag). So you can write your jQuery scripts after calling the jQuery library as,

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         ...
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Should optimally be called in the footer/end of the page for the relational loading order, but the `<head>` is alright for now.

Comment: @Darren that's why I wrote the "OR" section

Comment: @user3196511 glad it helped